# How to aggregate documents using $gt and aggregate Pymongo when the data is very nested

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have my data inside a a collection `collec` and then the data is very nested. I want to get all the data in my `db` which is having a `confidence> 0.33`.

I wrote a query like:

```
returned_data = {}
for q in collec.find({"question": {"$in":all_question_ids}})):
    if q['response']['detection']['confidence'] >= 0.3:
        returned_data[q['id1']] = q['response']['detection']['confidence']
```

This is taking too much time I think it is finding each and every entry individually.

How can I use `aggregate` with `$gt` to get the results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregate query to extract the relevant data using a pipeline i.e. a series of operations. First you'll match documents based on confidence greater than 0.3 then you can project the matched documents so you only return the required fields.

```
pipeline = [
    {'$match': {'response.detection.confidence': {'$gt': 0.3}}},
    {'$project': {'question_id': '$id1',
                  'confidence': '$response.detection.confidence'}
    ]

cursor = collec.aggregate(pipeline, useCursor=True, batchSize=50000) 
result = list(cursor)
```

Comment: What is `$id1` here? Also, you have indentation error which is not a big deal but my computer has been processing this query for the past 2 hours even when I used `.limit(10)`

Comment: `all_question_ids` is list of all the question ids I want to find. `[ObjectId('28_char_alphanum_id')],......]`

Comment: Based on your query I assumed `$id1` was is a key for question_id - is this wrong?

Comment: Re. `all_question_ids` You can match on multiple conditions using `$and`. For example - replace the `$match` statement in my code with this ```{'$match': {'$and': [{'response.detection.confidence': {'$gt': 0.3}}, {"question": {"$in":all_question_ids}}]}}```